# Rectangle tool properties adobe photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image: Screenshot]

What is the 2 color (black) next to normal red color ?

Comment: ...You can hover over it and it tells you.

Answer (score 0):

That is where you choose the `Stroke` color for your shape; it looks like that in every one of the Adobe Creative Suite apps (that I'm aware of anyway).